# Update data in ngDialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-dialog

I am using ngDialog in my project with data from my scope. I have a scope object named popupConge that I link to data of ngDialog :

```
ngDialog.open({ 
        template: 'saisieCongeModalPanel',
        className: 'ngdialog-theme-default width800',
        data: $scope.popupConge,
        scope: $scope,
    });
```

The problem is that when I update $scope.popupConge, the data in my modal panel aren't updated.
For instance I have: `<input type="text" id="motif" ng-model="ngDialogData.conge.motif"/>` in my ngDialog. When I update $scope.popupConge.conge.motif, the input field isn't updated :s

Did I do something wrong ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are passing `$scope` to the dialog you should use the `popupConge.conge.motif` instead.

Try this.

```
<input type="text" id="motif" ng-model="popupConge.conge.motif"/>
```

Comment: Yes that is what I am using now, this works. I thought that since the data property is available it is better to use it and not use the scope but well... didn't work ^^

Anyway, thanks